# Getting values from a dynamically created FormGroup and adding them up

Tags: angular

I'm creating a budget page where people can add as many rows of daily expenses as they need to and whatever they enter in the amount fields will be automatically added to a total above. I can do that easily with items that are static. I created an observer that watches for that field to change and just pass that value to the `totalReimbursement`. I'm having a hard time getting the values from the FormGroups generated in the FormArray.

You can see how I am adding them up and

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.aervform = this.fb.group({
      membersName: ["", [Validators.required]],
      lodgingExpense: [null, [Validators.required]],
      expenses: this.fb.array([this.addExpenseGroup()])
    });

    this.aervform.controls.lodgingExpense.valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
      this.add();
    });
  }

  addExpenseGroup(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      dateExpense: [null, [Validators.required]],
      bfast: [null, [Validators.required]],
      lunch: [null, [Validators.required]],
      dinner: [null, [Validators.required]]
    });
  }

  addExpense(): void {
    (<FormArray>this.aervform.get("expenses")).push(this.addExpenseGroup());
  }

  get expensesControls() {
    return <FormArray>this.aervform.get("expenses");
  }
```

Then I am looping through the controls

```
<div
  formArrayName="expenses"
  *ngFor="let expense of expensesControls.controls; let in = index">
  <hr *ngIf="in>0" />
  <div [formGroupName]="in">
     ...my expenses fields in here ...
  </div>
</div>
```

If you test the [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/expenses-calc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html), you will be abel to see the lodgingExpense field updating the total above, but if you add anything in the expenses, it doesn't (there is no code for it )...How can I capture these values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can watch for changes in the whole form and sum the expenses

Add this to your `ngOnInit`

```typescript
    this.aervform.valueChanges.pipe(
      map(({ lodgingExpense, expenses }) =>
            Number(lodgingExpense) +
            expenses
              .map(x => Object.entries(x))
              .flat()
              .filter(([x]) => {
                return ["bfast", "lunch", "dinner", "beverages", "gratuities" ].includes(x);
              })
              .map(([, x]) => x)
              .map(x => Number(x))
              .reduce((x, y) => x + y, 0)
        )
      )
      .subscribe(x => (this.totalReimbursement = x));
```

[See this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/expenses-calc-bzhsx5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: This is nice! Thank you

Comment: one issue. It added the date in the formArray as a value. It should only accept the amount fields.

Comment: Let me check and get back in a few

Comment: I believe the bug is now fixed

Answer (score 2):

You can use the value property on a formArray to get an array of the values of the controls.
Once you got an array you can loop on it with a for, or use the reduce method :

```js
    this.totalReimbursement = +this.aervform.get("lodgingExpense").value
        + this.aervform.get("expenses").value.reduce((sum, x) => sum + +x.bfast + +x.lunch + +x.dinner, 0)
```

In this exemple I use the + operator to coerce the values to numbers before adding them.

Comment: This is incredibly simple and clean. Thank you. +1 for that. I chose the other answer only because it was more pregrammatic. As in, it doesn't specify which specific items to add, but rather, it maps the values inside.